# how control robot wireless using RViz?

Tags: control, ros, rviz, wireless, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i try to build robot that work like turtlebot. i dont want buy turtlebot . how can i control my robot from Rviz and send command to real robot wia wifi ?  what hardware and circuit i need ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249944/how-control-robot-wireless-using-rviz-?/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-12-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-13**:
The Turtlebot has WiFi

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-12-15**:
For your custom robot, a WiFi dongle should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The turtlebot communicates with a desktop over WiFi. Buy a wifi adapter for your robot.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0